# deleting a comment oninstagram ad post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

Am trying to use this call to delete comment on an #Instagram ad post

```
curl -X DELETE -G \
-d "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>"\
-d "ad_id=<AD_ID>"\
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<INSTAGRAM_COMMENT_ID>"
```

however I get the following message

```
{"error":{"message":"Unsupported delete request. Object with ID does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. 
Please read the Graph API documentation at https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"At\/K4NqgQ+9"}}
```

I am sure that the ad_id is valid and the permission are not missing.

is there a better way to do, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/instagramads/post_moderation/v2.6, you need the comment ID as a URL parameter.

```
curl -X DELETE -G \
-d "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>"\
-d "ad_id=<AD_ID>"\
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<INSTAGRAM_COMMENT_ID>"
```

`https://graph.facebook.com//` as the Graph API URL just won't work.

Comment: I put the wrong request, I just edited the my question. i applied exactly like the documentation, and it not working, thanks @ceejayoz

Answer (score 0):

This has been confirmed as a bug in marketing api 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/261618244219382/